# Buffalo NAS LS220D on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: games, nas, obs-studio

I bought new the Buffalo NAS LS220D for about $200 recently, 2TB on two drives, for viewing across two Ubuntu PCs just for fun .mp4 video capture recorded off my gaming PC by OBS.  DayZ, space games, Valheim, etc.  All can be wiped anytime if needed, (and I like that sometimes - Fresh Starts!).  Used my old Iphone for setup of Buffalo LS220D NAS, since Buffalo 'Getting started', showed that option, went quickly, seems to have worked!  and still I can't view my files/folder in my PC running Ubuntu 23.10.  I may need to mount the drive.  I'm probably close!!!  The plan was a second slower ubuntu PC would upload throttled via wondershaper, to video sites, off a shared folder so my slow (trickle speed)...  doesn't affect the DSL.  Thought I'd setup through my Iphone, then view files on Ubuntu and no luck.  Happy to format things, starting over.  Formatting the Buffalo NAS if needed.  Just need a simple folder for video files between two Ubuntu PCs.  Also, I messaged a bit with Buffalo chat, and they seemed blunt, no support for Linux!.  Ugghhh... So I closed the chat.  I guess they need everyone on MAC OS, or Windows, but that's not me, and that's why I'm here.  Though I just made my askubuntu account, I'm long time Linux, sadly not a programmer in real job, work more with other sofware in job...  I have a separate physical modem, separate physical wifi router, then a different physical switch, lots of PC's in the house.  that might be the issue.  My Iphone sees the NAS just fine.  I setup the new password via my phone, or Buffalo getting started wouldn't start...  :)

Comment: You may have to set up SAMBA clients on both of your Ubuntu computers. Please add version number of the Ubuntu computers you have.

Comment: via terminal I just installed samba version 4.18.6-Ubuntu on gaming PC:  Gnome version 'Not Available' written, hmmm, and it's Ubuntu 23.10, not LTS. what else shall I provide about version number?  the other 'uploader' pc, has 22.04 LTS, I use Gnome everywhere.

Comment: samba 4.15.13 now on slower uploader PC (w/ Gnome Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS). This Samba must be the (SMB) i saw on by default on the Buffalo application view on my old Iphone.  Thanks!  getting closer.

Comment: A few restarts and folder:  ls220de0a is viewable from both PC's under ( + Other Locations).  I love user68186, you wrote to set up SAMBA clients.  This is a good community with good people.  Happy Holidays!!!  I'm so happy!!!

Comment: Now it would be great if you could write exactly what you did to get it to work by pressing the **Answer My Own Question** button below. Then accept your answer as correct. This will help others. By the way, welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Setup Buffalo LS220D via my old Iphone, made password long, saved to phone, changed from default.  Install SAMBA next.  Ubuntu terminal:
sudo apt install samba -y
Restarted PC's.  The gaming PC, restared twice.  Old PC showed drive after one restart.  The LS220D drive viewable in ( + Other Locations).  Version check in terminal:
samba -V
That "ON" SMB, shown on my Iphone (view options for LS220D - Buffalo Iphone app...), leave that on by default.
SMB = Samba.
Been uploading all night, Happy.